# Check if input value is the same as a ids value

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement

My first question on this platform. I have been working on a form that lets the user divide a certain number into smaller number of groups. I'm missing two things to make this complete before adding styles.

I need to be able to compare any given number in the #money input with the #sum input and see if they are equal/true.

Secondly, I need to set min and max for class targetDiv. So that the user can't set a number greater than 100 or smaller than 5.

I'm a beginner to jquery or at least I think I am, so any given help I appreciate you for :) Thanks!

Comment: Please include all relevant code (HTML) and what you have tried yourself to make this

Answer (score 0):

Basing **only** on the information you provided:

IDK, what you meant about these:

> My first question on this platform. I have been working on a form that lets the user divide a certain number into smaller number of groups. I'm missing two things to make this complete before adding styles.

But hope this helps you.

jQuery:

```
var money = $("#money").val();
var sum = $("#sum").val();
if(money !== sum){ console.log('true'); }
```

html:

`<input type="number" name="minMaxInput" min="5" min="100">`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Sorry I forgot to provide the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

         $('#showFive').click(function(){
               jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
        });
      $('#showFour').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4').show();
        });
        $('#showThree').click(function(){
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
            $('#div4,#div5').hide();
            $('#div1,#div2,#div3').show();
        });


            $('#div1, #vdiv2, #div3, #div4, #div5').keyup(function(){
               var div1 = parseFloat($('#div1').val()) || 0;
               var div2 = parseFloat($('#div2').val()) || 0;
               var div3 = parseFloat($('#div3').val()) || 0;
               var div4 = parseFloat($('#div4').val()) || 0;
               var div5 = parseFloat($('#div5').val()) || 0;
               $('#sum').val(div1 + div2 + div3 + div4 + div5);       // values (or variables) here
    });
        });
```

```css
body{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background: #eee;
}
div.menu{

   margin: 5% 10%;
   background: transparent;
}

.targetDiv{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Dividing money</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <input type="number" id="money" value="100" max="100" readonly />
  <div class="menu">
  <a  id="showThree" target="1">3 boxes</a>
  <a  id="showFour" target="3">4 boxes</a>
  <a  id="showFive">5 boxes</a>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div>
  <input type="number" id="div1" class="targetDiv" placeholder="Number1" min="???" step="0.5"/>
  <input type="number" id="div2" class="targetDiv" placeholder="Number2" min="???" step="0.5"/>
  <input type="number" id="div3" class="targetDiv" placeholder="Number3" min="???" step="0.5"/>
  <input type="number" id="div4" class="targetDiv" placeholder="Number4" min="???" step="0.5"/>
  <input type="number" id="div5" class="targetDiv" placeholder="Number5" min="???" step="0.5"/>
</div>

<input type="number" id="sum"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```